# Laravel REST API fetch a model with a relationship

Tags: laravel, rest

I'm trying to retrieve a model the following way:

```
        _id: 1, // ====> The model (example: Message)
          text: 'My message',
          createdAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 5, 11, 17, 20, 0)),
          user: { // ====> The model in the relationship, in this case, the USER
            _id: 2,
            name: 'React Native',
            avatar: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
          },
```

How is it possible for me to achieve this with laravel?

My current code looks this way:

```
public function show($id){
        $id = Group::where('id', $id)->first();
        return response()->json([
            'messages' => $id->messages,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look to JSON resources : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources

You can write your resource like :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Group extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            '_id' => $this->id,
            'text' => $this->text,
            'createdAt' => $this->created_at,
            // define the User resource too
            'user' => UserResource::collection($this->users)
        ];
    }
}
```

And then just use :

```
// use model binding here, it will retrieve your model from the ID
public function show(Group $group)
{
    return new GroupResource($group);
}
```

Comment: But, how is is possible for me to populate the array with the messages? I'm getting an empty array because I've not appended the messages to it, but how to append them? :)